# Laravel 5.2 every request will be to generate a new session file

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I've configured `config/session.php`

```
return [
    'driver' => 'file',
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
];
```

I put route rule in the group web

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
     Route::get('/example/demo', 'ExampleController@demo');
});
```

The folder of storage can be written **but every request will be to generate a new session file**

How did this happen?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure but this might be the case : Dont use `underscore` in `cookie`. Use `laravelsession` instead of `laravel_session`.

Comment: oh my god, it's ok, thanks!

Comment: do you know what's the matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem is in this line :

```
'cookie' => 'laravel_session'
```

I don't know what causes the problem, laravel or browser but you can not use `_` or `.` in cookie name.Removing underscore from cookie name will solve the problem.

And also i found this for IE : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx

Comment: Thank you times 1,000.  I could not figure this out. I was seeing this even for 'database' sessions.